# In Postgraphile How Do I Update/Delete a JOIN Table?

Tags: javascript, postgraphile

I am using Postgraphile (with the many-to-many plugin) with three tables: `foos`, `bars`, and `foo_bars`.  `foo_bars` is a simple join table with `foo_id` and `bar_id` columns, which have foreign key constraints to the corresponding table.

When I look at GraphiQL I can see that there *is* a `createFooBar` mutation, which let's me *create* a record in that JOIN table.  However, once I create a record, there appears to be no way to remove or change it, as there is no `updateFooBar` or `deleteFooBar` mutation, and neither the `updateFoo` or `updateBar` mutations seem to have a way to affect `foo_bar`.

So, simple question: how do I change JOIN table records in Postgraphile?

P.S. The relevant documentation page, https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/relations/, doesn't offer any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the update/delete mutations are missing on a table (join or otherwise) the most common reason is that there is no primary key or unique constraints on the table. Try adding a primary key to your table then restarting PostGraphile.